# Why can Chrome render a PNG image, but Firefox cannot?

Tags: image, firefox, png

Why can Chrome render the following PNG image, but Firefox cannot?

https://www.paycom.com/images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png

```
<img src="https://www.paycom.com/images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gu5aqzcL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it's an invalid PNG file, one of the `tEXt` chunks has an invalid CRC (checksum). Of course, some viewers can ignore that.

See for example http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/